# How to obtain a jpeg resolution in python 3, without any alien libraries?

Tags: python, image, jpeg, resolution

I'm  a rookie in python programming.  I can't find an answer, how to obtain jpeg resolution in python version 3. without using any external libraries.
I've tried this code, but result is unpredictable. And I don't understand why..

```
def jpeg_res(filename):

   # open image for reading in binary mode
   with open(filename,'rb') as img_file:

       # height of image (in 2 bytes) is at 164th position
       img_file.seek(163)

       # read the 2 bytes
       a = img_file.read(2)

       # calculate height
       height = (a[0] << 8) + a[1]

       # next 2 bytes is width
       a = img_file.read(2)

       # calculate width
       width = (a[0] << 8) + a[1]

   print("The resolution of the image is",width,"x",height)

jpeg_res("img1.jpg")
```

I'm using python version 3.5 working on MS Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: """# height of image (in 2 bytes) is at 164th position""" I would be astonished if that is always true.

Comment: JPEG doesn't have a simple header, where you can read the dimensions that easily. If you're interested, there's something for you: [read page 5](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/jfif3.pdf) As for your code - I happened to have on my desktop an image, for which with A3 (163) offset there were 4 bytes dimensions. Lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
def get_image_size(fname):
    '''Determine the image type of fhandle and return its size.
    from draco'''
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fhandle:
        head = fhandle.read(24)
        if len(head) != 24:
            return
        if imghdr.what(fname) == 'png':
            check = struct.unpack('>i', head[4:8])[0]
            if check != 0x0d0a1a0a:
                return
            width, height = struct.unpack('>ii', head[16:24])
        elif imghdr.what(fname) == 'gif':
            width, height = struct.unpack('<HH', head[6:10])
        elif imghdr.what(fname) == 'jpeg':
            try:
                fhandle.seek(0) # Read 0xff next
                size = 2
                ftype = 0
                while not 0xc0 <= ftype <= 0xcf:
                    fhandle.seek(size, 1)
                    byte = fhandle.read(1)
                    while ord(byte) == 0xff:
                        byte = fhandle.read(1)
                    ftype = ord(byte)
                    size = struct.unpack('>H', fhandle.read(2))[0] - 2
                # We are at a SOFn block
                fhandle.seek(1, 1)  # Skip `precision' byte.
                height, width = struct.unpack('>HH', fhandle.read(4))
            except Exception: #IGNORE:W0703
                return
        else:
            return
        return str(width) + "x" + str(height)
```

Full code on GitHub. https://goo.gl/w6U8Y7